# Javascript regex: match first 50 characters, respecting words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to keep some nav bar lines short by matching the first 50 chars then concatenating '...', but using `substr` sometimes creates some awkward word chops.
So I want to figure out a way to respect words.

I could write a function to do this, but I'm just seeing if there's an easier/cleaner way.

I've used this successfully in perl:

```
^(.{50,50}[^ ]*)
```

Nice and elegant!  But it doesn't work in Javascript :(

```
let catName = "A string that is longer than 50 chars that I want to abbreviate";
let regex = /^(.{50,50}[^ ]*)/;
let match = regex.exec(catName);
```

`match` is undefined

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `I could write a function to do this, but I'm just seeing if there's an easier/cleaner way.` Functions would be the most understandable way (for those coming behind you). Think about what a word actually is:  words can be hyphenated, be followed by punctuation, be quoted, etc. Are you going to neatly account for all of those in a regex alone?

Comment: _"So I want to figure out a way to respect words."_ What is expected result? Are you trying to get first fifty characters or first fifty words?

Comment: First 50 chars.  Actually, I mashed the first reply's answer with my original regex and this works: `let match = catName.match(/^(.{50,50}[^ ]*)/);`

Comment: @KennethK. sorry but that's going to be WAY easier to maintain than a function.  esp if I add a comment.

Comment: Actually, I see now why my original regex failed. It used in a loop and was choking on strings that had less than 50 chars :(

Comment: Famous last words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most fool-proof solution with regular expression would be to use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method instead. It won't fail with strings less than 50 characters:

```
str.replace(/^(.{50}[^ ]*).*/, '$1...');
```

```js
var str = 'A string that is longer than 50 chars that I want to abbreviate';
console.log( str.replace(/^(.{50}[^ ]*).*/, '$1...') );
```

Comment: ah! even better

Comment: @midget2000x Yeah, nice and short `:)`

Comment: one doubt... if 50th char is `a` and next is `.`(or any other symbol)

Comment: @PranavCBalan Yes, boundary would be ideal, if it was properly implemented in JavaScript engines.

Comment: @VisioN : anyway this looks simple :) ... I think adding the necessary char in negated character class will resolve that issue

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method with regex with [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to include the last word.

```
str.match(/^.{1,50}.*?\b/)[0]
```

```js
var str="I'm trying to keep some nav bar lines short by matching the first 50 chars then concatenating '...', but using substr sometimes creates some awkward word chops. So I want to figure out a way to respect words.";

console.log('With your code:', str.substr(0,50));
console.log('Using match:',str.match(/^.{1,50}.*?\b/)[0]);
```

Comment: Your code won't work with Unicode string, as boundary set in JS regex doesn't work with Unicode strings. Also it won't work with strings less than 50 characters.

Comment: @VisioN : yes that's true... I think for that we need to implement custom look ahead assertion(not sure)...

Comment: @VisioN : updated to work with string less than 50 char

Comment: I don't see the point of using boundary set if simple `[^ ]` worked well for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can `.split()` `\s`, count characters at each array element which contains a word at `for` loop, when `50` or greater is reached when `.length` of each word is accrued at a variable, `.slice()` at current iteration from array, `.join()` with space characters `" "`, `.concat()` ellipses, `break` loop.

```js
let catName = "A string that is longer than 50 chars that I want to abbreviate";

let [stop, res] = [50, ""];

if (catName.length > stop) {

  let arr = catName.split(/\s/);

  for (let i = 0, n = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    n += arr[i].length;
    if (n >= stop) {
      res = arr.slice(0, i).join(" ").concat("...");
      break;
    };
  }

} else {
  res = catName.slice(0, 50).concat("...")
}

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = res;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tinkering with Pranov's answer, I think this works and is most succinct:

```
// abbreviate strings longer than 50 char, respecting words
if (catName.length > 50) {  
    catName = catName.match(/^(.{50,50}[^ ]*)/)[0] + '...';
}
```

The regex in my OP *did* work, but it was used in a loop and was choking on strings that already had fewer than 50 chars.